# My text is not being displayed when using props (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-native-component

Components file:

```
function GoalItem(props) {
    return( 
          <Text style={Styles.prop}>{props.text}</Text>  
    );
}
export default GoalItem;
```

App file:

```
<FlatList data={(list)} renderItem={(itemData) => {
    <GoalItem text={(itemData.item.value)} />
}}
keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
    return item.id
}}/>
```

Comment: Please do not add random text to your post to get around the quality filter message: “It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details”. Instead, improve your question by including meaningful information about the issue or issues facing your implementation. See [ask] for more information

Answer (score 1):

Your `renderItem` function has no return statement. Try this:

```
<FlatList data={(list)} renderItem={(itemData) => {
          return <GoalItem text={(itemData.item.value)} />
        
      }}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
        return item.id
      }}/>
```